# Sort a field by reading numeric values from it

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by, numeric

I have a scenario where a field contains both character and number, I am suppose to sort it as given below.

`City 1
City 2
City 3
City 4a
City 4b
City 4c
City 10
City 11a
City 11b
Town 1
Town 2
Town 3a
Town 4b
Town 10`

The query should also take into account that in future more fields can be added like `100`, `101a`, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll have to split this into multiple columns with `substr`, tedious but I don't think there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible approach is using regular expressions.

Here is an example how to parse a string and divide in into subfields:

```
select col,
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+(\d+).*','\1') As field1,
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+(\D*),*.*','\1') As field2,
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+\D*,*(\d*)','\1') As field3
from table1
ORDER BY field1, field2, field3
;
```

If only a sort is required, then use these functions in ORDER BY clause:

```
select * from table1
order by
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+(\d+).*','\1'),
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+(\D*),*.*','\1'),
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+\D*,*(\d*)','\1')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f289/4

But for large dataset this will be horrible slow.
You need to normalize data in the table - parse it during insertion and store each field in separate column in the table, then create an index on these columns.

---

A sort using a cast to numeric:

```
select col,
    cast( regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+(\d+).*','\1') as numeric) As field1,
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+(\D*),*.*','\1')  As field2,
    cast( regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+\D*,*(\d*)','\1') As numeric) As field3
from table1
ORDER BY field1, field2, field3
;

select * from table1
order by
    cast( regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+(\d+).*','\1') as numeric),
    regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+(\D*),*.*','\1'),
    cast( regexp_replace( col, '\D+\s+\d+\D*,*(\d*)','\1') As numeric)
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f289/10

Comment: Hi Kordirko,
Thanks for the solution, but it's not giving desired solution.
After city 1 it is displaying city 10, what I need is city 1, city 2 and so on

Comment: Just use a cast to a numeric type, see an example in the answer. This is another reason why you need to normalize data ==> numbers are stored as strings.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I changed query a little, and am getting correct result now.

SELECT col, TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(col, '[0-9]+',1,1)) as x
FROM  t1
order by x

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
order by SUBSTRING(col_name, CHARINDEX(' ', col_name) + 1, len(col_name)-(CHARINDEX(' ', col_name)-1))
```

Here `SUBSTRING(col_name, from_index, till_index)` gives me substring between these indexes, and using `CHARINDEX` function I am finding indexes around second word of the string to extract it.

Please note, as par my understanding this will not use any index and can be slow if you have large data in the table.

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thanks for your solution. I was wondering if this will work on oracle?

Comment: I haven't tried these on oracle, I think if this not, there will be equivalent functions there as well.

Comment: this is similar to your query, it's updated for Oracle.

select *  from discreas order by substr(description,instr(' ',description)+1, length(description)-(instr(' ', description)-1))

However, it is not displaying desired result. It is giving city 10 after city 1. :(

Comment: yes, because you are doing order on a string, so it will give you result in lexicographical ordder.

Comment: You will have to further break second part of the string into integer and string and sort based on those 2 fields.